# How do I run a docker image on google container engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run a docker image in Google Container Engine. The instance comes up with no running docker images. I can ssh and run the docker commands and the service comes up. But nothing happens when I just launch the instance from the terminal. Can some one take a look at what I am doing wrong.

My docker file looks like

```
FROM golang
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
RUN go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/present
ENTRYPOINT cd /app && /go/bin/present -http=":8080"
EXPOSE 8080
```

containers.yaml looks like

```
version: v1beta3
containers:
  - name: talks
    image: sheki/talks 
    ports:
      - name: http-port
        containerPort: 8080
        hostPort: 80'
```

The command to launch the instance is

```
gcloud compute instances create zoop \
    --image container-vm \
    --metadata-from-file google-container-manifest=containers.yaml \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    --machine-type f1-micro
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your question that you are using google container engine, but in fact you are using the [container vm](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms) (which is a bit different). If you want to use container engine, please check out the documentation to create a [container cluster](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations).

I ran your example, and in `/var/log/kubelet.log` saw the following error:

```
E0519 17:05:41.285556    2414 http.go:54] Failed to read URL: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/attributes/google-cont
ainer-manifest: received 'version: v1beta3
containers:
  - name: talks
    image: sheki/talks 
    ports:
      - name: http-port
        containerPort: 8080
        hostPort: 80'
', but couldn't parse as neither single (error unmarshaling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int: {Version:v1beta3 ID: UUID:
 Volumes:[] Containers:[{Name:talks Image:sheki/talks Entrypoint:[] Command:[] WorkingDir: Ports:[{Name:http-port HostPort:0 ContainerPort:8080 Proto
col: HostIP:}] Env:[] Resources:{Limits:map[] Requests:map[]} CPU:0 Memory:0 VolumeMounts:[] LivenessProbe:<nil> ReadinessProbe:<nil> Lifecycle:<nil>
 TerminationMessagePath: Privileged:false ImagePullPolicy: Capabilities:{Add:[] Drop:[]}}] RestartPolicy:{Always:<nil> OnFailure:<nil> Never:<nil>} D
NSPolicy: HostNetwork:false}) or multiple manifests (error unmarshaling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []v1beta1.Container
Manifest: []) nor single (kind not set in '{"containers":[{"image":"sheki/talks","name":"talks","ports":[{"containerPort":8080,"hostPort":"80'","name
":"http-port"}]}],"version":"v1beta3"}') or multiple pods (kind not set in '{"containers":[{"image":"sheki/talks","name":"talks","ports":[{"container
Port":8080,"hostPort":"80'","name":"http-port"}]}],"version":"v1beta3"}').
```

It looks like the documentation for container vms is out of date.

Comment: Would you recommend using a container VM over  container cluster if I am only experimenting with docker containers and not planning any large infrastructure? I am likely to be creating applications with max 3 containers - web server, database +1 container running something like discourse.

Comment: I'm biased, but I think using a container cluster is simpler even for a small number of containers, since it allows you to easily redeploy your containers when you want to change them (such as when you upgrade the software). It also allows you to configure your containers to all run on one machine (e.g. when you are developing locally) and then scale them out to multiple machines when you deploy to a cloud provider.